# Redirect user to Sign In page after Sign Up (registration)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise 3.1.1 and am trying to redirect user to the Sign In page after he signs up.
As instructed in [Devise's wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29) I overridden RegistrationsController with the following:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/users/sign_in'
  end
end
```

As instructed, I also added the following line to the `routes.rb`:

`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}`

After which I get the following error when I go to sign in page:

`Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as`option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.`

In my routes I already have this defined:

```
  devise_for :users, skip: :registrations
  devise_scope :user do
    resource :registration,
      # disabled :edit & :destroy
      only: [:new, :create, :update],
      path: 'users',
      path_names: { new: 'sign_up' },
      controller: 'devise/registrations',
      as: :user_registration do
        get :cancel
      end
  end
```

Comment: Are there two `devise_for` blocks in your routes?

Comment: @JonathanBender yes, `devise_for :users, skip: :registrations` and `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}`. I guess I need to write them as one somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only define the `devise_for` block once, and as you're already messing with the default registrations controller you should be able to just do something like the following to have devise use your controller:

```
devise_for :users, skip: :registrations
devise_scope :user do
  resource :registration,
    # disabled :edit & :destroy
    only: [:new, :create, :update],
    path: 'users',
    path_names: { new: 'sign_up' },
    controller: 'registrations',
    as: :user_registration do
      get :cancel
    end
end
```